# UITableviewCell height autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have following UITableviewCell layout, I am using autolayout for handling this

```
========= 
| Image | Name Label
|       | Short description Label
=========
Description Label
```

Here Description Label is optional, it will hide/show according to content, I am calculating height of cell on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` using

```
- (CGFloat)heightForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize cellSize = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    // Add extra padding
    CGFloat height = cellSize.height;// + 1;

    return height;
}
```

Even if I hide hide Description Label it is returning the same height for cell, What I am missing ?

Can anyone suggest best way to handle such scenarios with autolayout ?

**Edit 1** : Setting empty works but is there any better way ?

Comment: Can show the full code of calculating cell height?

Comment: Where you are hiding label? before this method is getting called?

Comment: Yes while configuring it with model

Comment: could you please try by setting an empty string to detailLabel

Comment: Setting empty works but is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0):

heightForRowAtIndexPath is also called for all the rows.So for the row which  you are hiding description label, for the same row you cat set height in heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

For example. 
for row no 4 you  want to  hide description label by checking some condition.

than in heightForRowAtIndexPath you  can check same condition for the same row, and you  can return the height that is required while not  showing description label.

Lets say,

```
if(description.length==0)
 {
    return 100;//  description label hidden
 }
else 
 {
   return 140;//  description label shown
 }
```

Comment: I have updated method for calculating cell height, I just want it to return exact value

Comment: forget that  method for calculating cell height, just try what i said . i t must work

Comment: I have lots of different cells so I cant simply use that

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calculating height of each cell as follow. By looking at your question, I am assuming that all cells should have same height if there is no description label, correct ? Lets assume it is 60. So, all you need to do is calculate height of each cell depending on its description text and add it in the height of cell which would be without the description text. Which would be something like this in your `heightForTableView` delegate.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int cellWidth = 320; // assuming it is 320
    int constantHeight = 60;

    NSString * str = [[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DescriptionKey"];

    int height = [self calculateHeightForText:str withWidth:cellWidth andFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
    // replace systemFontSize with your own font

    return height + constantHeight;
}
// Depreciated in iOS7
- (int)calculateHeightForText:(NSString *)string withWidth:(int)width andFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize textSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 20000) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return ceil(textSize.height);
}
// Introduced in iOS7
- (int)calculateHeightForText:(NSString *)string withWidth:(int)width andFont:(UIFont *)font
{

    int maxHeightForDescr = 1000;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

    CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, maxHeightForDescr)
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                    attributes:attributes
                                       context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

I have written two methods for calculateHeightForText, one is depreciated in iOS7 and works for both iOS6 and less and iOS7 but the 2nd one is recommended method for iOS7 but will not work for iOS7. Do let me know if you find something confusing, or need any further help with this. Would be glad to help out further.